# Chrome page in Firefox addon cannot access tabs

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm new to Firefox addon development and am having some trouble finding a solution to my problem in the MDN documentation. My addon is very simple right now, I have a main.js file that opens a new chrome page

```
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

var button = buttons.ActionButton({
  id: "mozilla-link",
  label: "Visit Mozilla",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
  onClick: handleClick
});
var addontab = require("sdk/addon-page");
var data = require("sdk/self").data;

function handleClick(state) {
require("sdk/tabs").open(data.url("chrome://test_addon/content/data/index.html"));
}
```

Inside that chome page I want to access a list of open tabs; however, this is where I run into a problem. Adding necessary JS, such as the code below results in an error:

```
var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');
for (let tab of tabs)
console.log(tab.title);
```

Here is the error, I am obviously calling the script improperly, but I don't know how I'm supposed to be implementing this.

```
JavaScript error: chrome://test_addon/content/data/index.html, line 12: require is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that runs in the context of `chrome://test_addon/content/data/index.html` is not sandboxed, so it can't access the SDK APIs.

Comment: This makes perfect sense; however, I am having a hard time finding out how to sandbox that code. Should I be using this functionality to sandbox my script https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.Sandbox ? Thank you!

Comment: It's not that simple, actually I don't know it's possible for Addon SDK to sandbox a chrome page. Do you really need this page to be registred with chrome?

Comment: The page was registered with chrome because I am trying to make a very large and involved interface that needs a dedicated page. What if I setup JS within the SDK sandboxing (such as in a toolbar panel) to pass the necessary data to my chomed page, and then back again? Would that even be possible? Thanks!